# Composer packages for functions. Bad form?

Tags: php, composer-php, package

I just recently got into (learned how to) making composer packages, and want to distribute some functions I've made over the years.

I understand that you can autoload files containing just functions by using the `files` autoloader, but I was wondering what the "best practice limit" is for doing this.

Namely: Is it acceptable to distribute composer packages containing only functions? What about single functions?

Comment: The very important [`ircmaxell/password_compat`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library works that way. I would consider it acceptable. Don't try to make classes out of things that aren't object-oriented, if that is what you would think the alternative to be. In any case though, this is a little too opinion-oriented for a SO question.

Comment: Could you package them at least as static methods in a class? You can't autoload on functions only, remember.

Comment: Probably more important is namespacing. You _can_ namespace functions and should if you are going to distribute them.

Comment: @halfer Functions can be loaded by composer using the `files` directive. Example: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/composer.json Though I think they're just "auto-included" rather than loaded dynamically at runtime.

Comment: @Michael, yes to both. It's not autoloading as such, but it does the job just fine.

Comment: You know what, I am ok with this getting held.  Thanks guys/gals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is very acceptable.

The composer documentation states:

> It allows you to declare the dependent libraries your project needs and it will install them in your project for you.

If your functions can be seen as a software package there is no reason why you should not publish them via. composer. There are countless composer-packages out there only consisting of a single class or even a single interface.

But you should try to group functions that belong together in one composer-package.